# artifactory max unique snapshots in nuget repository

Tags: nuget, artifactory, purge

Local NuGet repositories configured in Artifactory have an option "max unique snapshots". However, the snapshot notion does not really exist in NuGet. So what effect does this configuration have?

Comment: This is the kind of question that you should direct to Artifactory support team.

Answer (score 2):

> However, the snapshot notion does not really exist in NuGet.

It kind of does, with the notion of [**pre-release**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages).

> Pre-release versions are then denoted by appending a hyphen and a string after the patch number.
>   Technically speaking, you can use *any *string after the hyphen and NuGet will treat the package as pre-release. NuGet then displays the full version number in the applicable UI, leaving consumers to interpret the meaning for themselves.

Snapshots are also mentioned in [NuGet issue 1891](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1891) and [issue 2544](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/c), but Artifactory might simply keep only the last "max snapshots" pre-releases for any given x.y.z version.